# ERROR: only temporary relations may be created in temporary schemas

Tags: postgresql

Today I want to test some new feature of PostgreSQL 9.1, It's unlogged table, but it turns out the follwoing Error, anyone can help me?

```
mydb=> CREATE UNLOGGED table testu (a int);
ERROR:  only temporary relations may be created in temporary schemas

mydb=> select version();
                                                  version                                                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.1beta3 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48), 32-bit
(1 row)
```

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)

Comment: How did you create the schema? And maybe you should use the final release and not a beta version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a bug in the Beta, it [has been fixed a while ago](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2011-08/msg00084.php). Install the production release and your problem goes away.

http://www.postgresql.org/download/